# define `current_user` for rails_admin without devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin, cancancan

I am trying to setup `rails_admin` with the following

```
config.authorize_with :cancancan
config.current_user_method { current_user }
```

I am not using `devise` because an enterprise level SSO handles authentication and passes me the username. The app is only responsible for authorization (`cancancan`). I have a simple implementation of `current_user` in `ApplicationController`:

```
def current_user
  user = User.find_by(:UserName => session[:user])
  return user
end
```

This has worked just fine for `cancancan` but `rails_admin` doesn't understand. I get the following error. What am I missing?

`` NoMethodError (undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass):
  rails_admin (1.0.0) lib/rails_admin/config.rb:153:in `block in authorize_with'
  rails_admin (1.0.0) app/controllers/rails_admin/application_controller.rb:52:in `instance_eval'
  rails_admin (1.0.0) app/controllers/rails_admin/application_controller.rb:52:in `_authorize!'
  activesupport (4.2.7.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:432:in `block in make_lambda'
  activesupport (4.2.7.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:164:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.7.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.7.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `each'
  activesupport (4.2.7.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.7.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.7.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.7.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.7.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.7.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.7.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.7.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.7.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.7.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.2.7.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.7.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.2.7.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.7.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
  actionview (4.2.7.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.7.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.7.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.7.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.7.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.7.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.7.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.7.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
  actionpack (4.2.7.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.7.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:817:in `call'
  railties (4.2.7.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.7.1) lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
  railties (4.2.7.1) lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
  actionpack (4.2.7.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:51:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.7.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.7.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
  actionpack (4.2.7.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.7.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:817:in `call'
  rack-pjax (1.0.0) lib/rack/pjax.rb:12:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.7.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  remotipart (1.3.1) lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:32:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.7.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.7.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.7.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.7.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.7.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.7.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.7.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.7.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.7.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.7.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.7.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.7.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.7.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.7.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.7.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.7.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.7.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.7.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.7.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.7.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.7.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.7.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.7.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.7.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:120:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.7.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.7.1) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
  puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb:578:in `handle_request'
  puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb:415:in `process_client'
  puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb:275:in `block in run'
  puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:116:in `block in spawn_thread' ``

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in your `ApplicationController`:

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end
helper_method :current_user
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! I put in that change and get the same error.

Comment: your actual error says undefined method `new` for nil class. Find what that nil class is. Somewhere you're calling `.new` on something that's nil. Find where that is.

Answer (score 0):

In `config/initializers/rails_admin.rb` you have to add the `authorize_with` method:

```
config.authorize_with do
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic('Login required') do |username, password|
      user = User.where(email: username, admin: true).first
      user && user.authenticate(password)
    end
  end
```

Once that done, your user is authenticated and you can use the `current_user` variable